# this.state not the same as state in this object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've run into a problem where I load initial data by doing an AJAX call in `componentDidMount` and set state in the callback for said AJAX call. I also wish to manipulate my data immediately after so I call another function in the `setState` callback. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
filterData(area) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.state);
  console.log(this.state.data);

  ... // The implementation of my filter
}

componentDidMount() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onloadend = () => {
    console.log('* AJAX POST Response Received *');
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
      this.setState({ data: JSON.parse(xhr.response) },
        this.filterData(this.area)
      );
    } else {
      console.error('[ERROR] Server returned invalid response');
    }
  };
}
```

When I look through the state in my `this` object, I can find the proper state data that I'm expecting but `this.state` and `this.state.data` are initial values set in my constructor. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

#### Edit

So I guess I left out something in my code snippet. My filtering function actually invokes `this.setState` to store the filtered data in state. I think this is actually what was causing my problem.

Revised snippet:

```
filterData(area) {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(this.state);
  console.log(this.state.data);

  ... // The implementation of my filter
  this.setState({ filtered_data: filtered });
}
```

My Current Solution:

```
filterData(area, all_data) {
  if(this.state.data || all_data) {
    ... // The implementation of my filter
  }
  this.setState({ filtered_data: filtered });
}

componentDidMount() {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onloadend = () => {
    console.log('* AJAX POST Response Received *');
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
      this.filterData(this.area, JSON.parse(xhr.response));
    } else {
      console.error('[ERROR] Server returned invalid response');
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `setState` must be a function. Try this instead:

```
this.setState({
    data: JSON.parse(xhr.response)
}, () => this.filterData(this.area));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the problem still occurs

Comment: Actually, when I modify my code to try this solution, it seems like `filterData` isn't even run because the logs aren't displaying anymore either

Comment: Sorry my original answer used a traditional `function`, I've changed it to an arrow function to ensure `this` binds. Make sure you're doing this.

Comment: Ya, I did that when I was testing it out but still no luck

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can also use `.bind` if you want to get rid of the anonymous function. http://jsbin.com/kifekamano/

Comment: Hm, ok. The problem must be somewhere else in my code then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

setState causes a competent to re-render, making anything you do after it irrelevant as far as react is concerned. You need to hook into the component lifecycle later, like componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate to run your filter function.

Comment: setState takes a callback argument that is supposed to fire only after state has been modified.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html